# What's the canonical "append file 1 to file 2" groovy code snippet?

Tags: file, groovy

I've searched Google & the [File Recipes](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Recipes+For+File), but I haven't found the canonical way to do:

```
cat a.txt b.txt > c.txt
```

in groovy. Here is one suggestion:

```
def appendFile(File src, File target) {
    def newline = System.getProperty('line.separator')

    src.eachLine { line ->
        target << line
        target << newline
    };
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass an InputStream to [`File.leftShift`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#leftShift%28java.lang.Object%29), it will append the contents of the stream to the file. I'd do something like this:

```
src.withInputStream { input ->
    target << input
}
```

Comment: Would that leave a FileInputStream hanging?

Comment: better might be (assuming `target` and `src` are Files): `src.withReader { target << it }`

Comment: A `Reader` interprets characters according to an encoding.  Unless you specifically need to handle text encodings, an `InputStream` probably makes more sense here.

Comment: I think `<<` will open the file every time, and might be a bit slow.

Comment: @ripper every time?  It does the whole file at once

Comment: @tim_yates - ah, I wasn't aware of this. Interesting.